# An element of an extension field has a rational function with coefficients in the field that equals it

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I stumbled across a statement without proof that I am having a hard time understanding or providing myself with intuition for. Any help would be most appreciated.

The statement reads:

Since $\xi$ is in $k(\eta)$, this means that there are polynomials $v$, $u$, with coefficients in $k$, and without common factors of positive degree, such that $v(\eta)\not=0$ and $\xi = u(\eta)/v(\eta)$

Comment: What's the definition of $k(\eta)$? Ordinarily, this is the field of fractions of $k[\eta]$.

Comment: It this is in the context of some field extension of $k$ containing $\eta$, then the definition of $k(\eta)$ is the smallest subfield containing $k$ and $\eta$. Try to show that this is the image of the fraction field $k(X)$ by the isomorphism over $k$ sending $X\mapsto\eta$ in case $\eta$ is transcendental over $k$ (in this case $v(\eta)=0$ only occurs is $v=0$), and otherwise the homomorphic image of $k[X]$ by a similar homomorphism (which does have a nonzero kernel). In the later case you can just take $v=1$ and $u$ of bounded degree; the statement is formulated so as to hold in both cases.